# String printing causes a C program to crash

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

The following code crashes for some reason producing the following message "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". Debugger says there is a segmentation fault in this line:

```
printf("|%s|", grid[a][b]);
```

However, I think this is not the actual mistake meaning something must go wrong before. Since I'm not very experienced with strings and arrays in C could you please have a look on my code and see if you can find the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VALUES1 3
#define VALUES2 3
#define NAMELEN 10

void printgrid(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2]);
void play(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2], char player);
int game(void);


int main() {

    return game();
}


int game() {
    char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2], player, turn, names[2][NAMELEN];
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < 2; ++a){
        printf("Please enter the name of player number %d\n", a + 1);
        scanf("%s", names[a]);
    }

    for (a = 0; a < VALUES1; ++a){
        for (b = 0; b < VALUES2; ++b){
            grid[a][b] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (turn = 9; turn > 0; --turn){
        if (turn % 2 == 1){
            player = names[0];
        }
        else {
            player = names[1];
        }
        play(grid, player);
        printf("\n");
        printgrid(grid);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


void printgrid(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2]) {
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < VALUES1; ++a) {
        for (b = 0; b < VALUES2; ++b) {
            printf("|%s|", grid[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void play(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2], char player) {
    int row, column;

    printf("Enter the row number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter the column number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &column);

    --row;
    --column;

    grid[row][column] = player;
}
```

Edit:
Output using %c

```
|þ||þ||þ|
|±||±||þ|
|±||±||þ|
```

Comment: `grid[a][b]` is a `char`, not a string, so you should use the `%c` format in `printf` (or use `putchar`). Your compiler can tell you that if you instruct it to by enabling all warnings.

Comment: As @MOehm noted, `%s` will expect a character array. You're passing it a character literal. So printf is reading forward into the memory looking for a null terminator. Hence why you get a segmentation fault. Nearly anytime a function reads forward into memory which is not its own, the program crashes. `%c` is what you'll need.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more specific. "C program crashes" explains nothing specific about the problem you're having, and will be totally meaningless if it turns up in a search by future users of this site. It's no more meaningful than "my car won't work" would be to your auto repair person.

Comment: Thanks! Firstly, I would like to print a string not just a character. How should I alter my code to achieve that? Secondly, %c does not crash the program but the playing characters are the same all the time. I would like the code to print the name to the square after they have played the square!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your use of `player`. You designate it as a `char` yet attempt to assign a `char*` value to it. You mix its use between `char` and `char *` throughout your functions. The intent is clear. You want to use the **first character** in `name[0]` and `name[1]` in building the game grid during play. You can do it this way, but you must be **very careful** in its use.

Additionally, compiling your code, **always** turn warnings on. They would immediately direct you to the problems in your code:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/play play.c

play.c: In function ‘game’:
play.c:36:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
            player = names[0];
                    ^
play.c:39:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
            player = names[1];
                    ^
play.c: In function ‘printgrid’:
play.c:56:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
            printf("|%s|", grid[a][b]);
            ^
```

One solution to bring consistency to the use of `player` is to declare it as `char *` and then `dereference` it when you need to use `player` as a char (i.e. `*player` which in full form is `*(player + 0)` equivalent to `player[0]`) A solution looks like:

```
int game() {
    char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2], turn, names[2][NAMELEN];
    char *player;
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < 2; ++a){
        printf("Please enter the name of player number %d\n", a + 1);
        scanf("%s", names[a]);
    }

    for (a = 0; a < VALUES1; ++a){
        for (b = 0; b < VALUES2; ++b){
            grid[a][b] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (turn = 9; turn > 0; --turn){
        if (turn % 2 == 1){
            player = names[0];
        }
        else {
            player = names[1];
        }
        play(grid, *player);
        printf("\n");
        printgrid(grid);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


void printgrid(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2]) {
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < VALUES1; ++a) {
        for (b = 0; b < VALUES2; ++b) {
            printf("|%c|", grid[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/play
Please enter the name of player number 1
Don
Please enter the name of player number 2
Millie
Enter the row number:
1
Enter the column number:
2

| ||D|| |
| || || |
| || || |
...
Enter the row number:
3
Enter the column number:
1

|M||D||D|
|D||M||M|
|D||M||D|
```

As an aside, you can improve the output of `printgrid` to eliminate the double `||` in the inner columns with a simple `if` statement:

```
void printgrid(char grid[VALUES1][VALUES2]) {
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < VALUES1; ++a) {
        for (b = 0; b < VALUES2; ++b) {
            if (b == 0)
                printf("|%c|", grid[a][b]);
            else
                printf("%c|", grid[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
|M|D|D|
|D|M|M|
|D|M|D|
```